# Excel VBA Match row with 2 variables

Tags: excel, vba, forms, variables, match

I have a table I need to return a single value from a row based on two variables. If the source of the variables was in a spreadsheet, I could do this with  `=INDEX(Col3, MATCH(var1 & var2, Col1 & Col2, 0))`. My problem is that *var1* and *var2* are coming from a VBA form instead of cells in a worksheet. When I try to match on these variables in VBA using the same method, VBA is combining the separate strings into one and returning an error.

In the below table, the expected return would be *Luke Skywalker* when given *Squadron = Red* and *Call Sign = Five*. What I'm getting is my script trying to match *RedFive* instead which generates an error due to the one critera vs two ranges to search.

On the form:
*TextBox1* = `Sq.Value` = Squadron
*TextBox2* = `CallSn.Value` = Call Sign
*Sheet1* is the data which is 49,750 lines in my original (not related to Star Wars) and the original data columns are not ordered as neatly as this example. This is imported data.

```
rw = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sq.Value & CallSn.Value, Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A:A") & Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("B:B"), 0)
Pilot= Worksheets(Sheet1).Cells(rw, 3)
```

The result needs used in other processes in the script. (ie looking up the pilot's status on a different table)

Example Data:

| Squadron | Call Sign | Pilot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Leader | Garven Dreis |
| Red | Two | Wedge Antilles |
| Red | Three | Biggs Darklighter |
| Red | Four | John D. Branon |
| Red | Five | Luke Skywalker |
| Red | Six | Jek Porkins |
| Red | Seven | Elyhek Rue |
| Red | Eight | Zal Dinnes |
| Red | Nine | Nozzo Naytaan |
| Red | Ten | Theron Nett |
| Red | Eleven | Ralo Surrel |
| Red | Twelve | Puck Naeco |
| Gold | Leader | Jon "Dutch" Vander |
| Gold | Two | Dex Tiree |
| Gold | Three | Evaan Verlainer |
| Gold | Four | Jake Farrell |
| Gold | Five | Davish Krail |
| Gold | Six | Brace Marko |
| Gold | Seven | Gazdo Woolcob |
| Gold | Eight | Datchi Creel |

Comment: Pass the `INDEX/MATCH` formula as a string to `Worksheet.Evaluate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me. I used a variant of Tim Williams (https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) solution.

Issues I had with the original answer and my version of Office 365 were

1. My version didn't accept ""&"" as a & in the string. Solved with Chr(38).
2. Quotes, Chr(34), were needed in the formula string around the strings being searched for.
3. My version doesn't have `Worksheets(Sheet1).Evaluate` as an option.

Because my inputs are coming from text boxes on forms, the data searched is imported, and the output of this block is being used further on in my code, this is what I ended up using...

```
Dim f As String

f = "=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(" & Chr(34) & Sq.Value & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & _ 
      Chr(38) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & CallSn.Value & Chr(34) & _ 
      ", 'Sheet1'!A:A" & Chr(32) & Chr(38) & Chr(32) & "'Sheet1'!B:B,0),1)"

'The worksheet version of Evaluate didn't exist in my version of Excel, so went with the VBA version.

Debug.Print Evaluate(f)
```

Comment: "The worksheet version of Evaluate didn't exist in my version of Excel" - what version are you using - that has been around for a long time....  Everything else in my answer should also be fine in any version of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim rw
    rw = MatchedPilot("Red", "Two")
    If Not IsError(rw) Then
        Debug.Print "Matched pilot " & rw
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Match"
    End If
End Sub

'Match a pilot on "Squadron" and "Call Sign"
Function MatchedPilot(squad, callSign)
    Dim f As String
    f = "=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(""" & squad & """&""" & callSign & """,A:A&B:B,0),1)"
    Debug.Print f
    'use the worksheet version of Evaluate
    MatchedPilot = Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(f)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

just to give some alternative approaches

**1) USE OF D functions**

you could place some helpers cells in Sheet1

[image]

and use them in your code as follows:

```
Dim pilot As String
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("G2").Value = Sq
    .Range("H2").Value = CallSn
    
    .Calculate
    pilot = .Range("I2").Value
End With
```

**2) USE OF `AutoFilter`**

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Sq
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=CallSn

        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                pilot = .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3).Value
            End If
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

**3) USE OF Dictionary**

```
Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim pilot As String
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                dict.Add cel.Value & "|" & cel.Offset(, 1).Value, cel.Offset(, 2).Value
            Next
            pilot = dict(Sq & "|" & CallSn)
        End With
```

Comment: None of these are useful in my case. 1) The original table is imported and I don't want to be playing with extra cells on that page. 2) The return needs to be used in following code. The sample is just a segment that was the problem block. Filtering is only useful for a human and not the following code. 3) The original data is 49,750 lines long. Dictionary will be a slow method with that much data.

Comment: @KeeslerWaterWalker , 1) I see. 2) I don't get you: what would prevent the filtering result to be used in any other portion of the code? 3) Dictionary are very fast, instead. Have you ever worked with them?  4) Sorry if i bothered you by giving possible solution for your problem