# Worksheetfunction.Match on 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

Match is working fine with two columns in a worksheet formula. Worksheetfunction.Match is working fine with single columns, but not with two columns. How can I get Worksheetfunction.Match to work with 2 columns like Match?

First, for reference, these three worksheet formulas are all working as expected. The third one finds a row where both criteria match:

```
=MATCH("520002944190",C:C,0)
=MATCH("j1234",A:A,0)
=MATCH("520002944190"&"j1234",C:C&A:A,0)
```

And these two are working fine, in VBA's Immediate pane:

```
?WorksheetFunction.Match("520002944190",rgTableColSku.EntireColumn)
?WorksheetFunction.Match("j1234",rgVPNs.EntireColumn)
```

But this returns an error:

```
?WorksheetFunction.Match("520002944190"&"j1234",rgTableColSku.EntireColumn&rgVPNs.EntireColumn)
```

Can I use WorksheetFunction.Match on two columns?

Comment: No. Use `Worksheet.Evaluate` and pass it the formula as a `String`.

Comment: Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77404296/excel-vba-match-row-with-2-variables/77404370#77404370